# Debian: samba mount fail "mount error(115): Operation now in progress"

Tags: linux, debian, mount, samba

- I have a sinalogy diskstation
- I try to mount a share in debian
- Throw error (problem is same if vers=1.0, and without vers)

```
$ mount -t cifs -o username=m.somogyi,vers=2.0 //192.168.0.200/Kozos /mnt/ds1-common/
Password for m.somogyi@//192.168.0.200/Kozos:  ***************
mount error(115): Operation now in progress
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

- dmesg

```
[67709.365595] CIFS VFS: Error connecting to socket. Aborting operation.
[67709.366507] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -115
```

- list of share is working

```
# smbclient -L FILESERVER -U m.somogyi
Enter WORKGROUP\m.somogyi's password:

        Sharename       Type      Comment
        ---------       ----      -------
...
        Kozos           Disk
...
```

- direct IP not working

```
smbclient -L 192.168.0.200 -U m.somogyi
do_connect: Connection to 192.168.0.200 failed (Error NT_STATUS_IO_TIMEOUT)
```

- If I add FILESERVER to /etc/hosts the problem is same
- Connect to share in windows (7,8,10 etc.) is working correctly
- system version

```
$ uname -a
Linux msdebian 4.19.0-17-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.194-3 (2021-07-18) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct IP address then? Perhaps Samba translates `-L FILESERVER` to a completely different address than 192.168.0.200?

Comment: Sorry, I was lame :( Correct IP address is 192.168.0.220, and works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a mistake and the correct IP address is `192.168.0.220`